# Why pymongo change my variable after insert_one operation?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I faced this while writing some tests to a new class method.

```
>>> doc = {'test': True}
>>> collection.insert_one(doc)
<pymongo.results.InsertOneResult object at 0x031C2D00>
>>> doc
{'test': True, '_id': ObjectId('5e7103a1b650bd01fac6c6ff')}
```

Why the key `_id` was added to the variable `doc`? There's a way to avoid this behaviour from `pymongo`?

Comment: That behavior is defined the the MongoDB driver spec.  If you call insert and the _id field is not already populated, one will be automatically generated.  To avoid that, make sure _id has a value before you insert.

Comment: I understand why Mongo must include the `_id` field in the database, but why it also add in my `dict` variable defined within the python console?

Comment: Because it is added to the object by the python driver, before sending the query to the server.

Comment: Here's the [FAQ](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html#why-does-pymongo-add-an-id-field-to-all-of-my-documents) from the docs, you're not alone in asking the question. One of the main reasons is that the mongo server would add the _id but not report it back to pymongo.

Answer (score 3):

from the [docs](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_one):

> insert_one(document, bypass_document_validation=False, session=None)
>
> (...)
>
> Parameters:     document: The document to insert. Must be a mutable
> mapping type. If the document does not have an _id field one will be
> added automatically.

Comment: Yeah, but why it also added in my `dict` variable defined within the python console? I understand why Mongo must include the `_id` field in the database, but why `doc` must change as well?

Comment: your dict will be understood as a document, so mongo will add the _id in your document for you to be easier to find your document in mongo, imagine that you have millions of documents, how you could find back your document? if not using this _id